# Git submodule on remote bare

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-bare

I've setup my environment so I can push to a remote bare repository.  I used these commands to set up the remote repository:

```
$ mkdir ~/website.git && cd ~/website.git
$ git init --bare
```

And

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/website git checkout -f

$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

And on my local environment:

```
$ git remote add web ssh://website.com/home/website.git
$ git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

Now I can deploy to this remote using `git push web`, and everything works great..

### The problem: Submodules

I have a few **submodules** on my project that aren't getting initialized/updated at the remote repository. I can't run `git submodule update` on the bare because it's bare, and I can't run it on the `/var/www/website` folder because it's just a copy of the files and not a git repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible way might be:

- to setup `/var/www/website` as a (non-bare) repo
- have your `post-receive` hook of your bare repo:

  - set `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` to the non-bare repo at `/var/www/website`
  - `cd /var/ww/website`
  - `git pull ~/website`
  - `git submodule update` (a bit like in "[How do I init/update a git submodule in a working tree after pushing to a bare working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611171/6309)")

In other words:
Pull from the bare repo instead of trying to checkout from a bare repo: a non-bare repo should be able then to accommodate the `git submodule update` step.

An example script may look like

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the latest code
cd /path/to/bare/repo

# Set git variables
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/website
GIT_DIR=/var/www/website/.git

# Go to website and pull
cd /var/www/website
git pull /path/to/bare/repo
git submodule update --init --recursive

# Run additional build stuff here
```

Comment: Can you provide an example for the post-receive / post-update script (although this answer is pretty old)? Every time I try to push I gets errors.

Comment: remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '/var/www/website'

Comment: @raveN is there a `.git` folder in `/var/www/website`?

Comment: yes :) I cloned the repository as non-bare (as you have written)

Comment: Is `GIT_DIR` set to `/var/ww/website/.git` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` to `/var/ww/website/`?

Comment: Ahhh, the GIT_DIR wasn't set to .git - thank you so much for your fast help. I will edit your answer to provide a full example.

Comment: @VonC do you think it's necessary to `git fetch`? I ran into the same problem and solved it as you suggested without fetching. because fetching requires origin and in this case `bare repo` has to point it to itself.

Comment: @johnshumon Right! I have removed the unnecessary step. Not sure what I was thinking about when I write this answer 6 years ago...

Answer (score 14):

I figured out another solution which looks rather clean to me. Just give git all the info it needs to perform the submodule stuff:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/git_work_tree
$ git --git-dir=/path/to/your/bare_repo.git --work-tree=. submodule init
$ git --git-dir=/path/to/your/bare_repo.git --work-tree=. submodule update
```

Comment: How can you automate this so that it does this after each `push` deployment?

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled across this thread two days ago while I struggled with the same issue. After finally arriving at a nice, tidy solution, I wrote an article about it here:

[Git push with submodules: a how-to guide](http://aaronadams.ca/post/37345904654/git-push-with-submodules#solution)

I realized that if I'm going to `push` to a bare repo, only to use `post-receive` to `pull` into a non-bare repo, I might as well just keep it simple and `push` directly to the non-bare repository. This is a clear case where the "best practice" of only pushing to a bare repo is only adding complexity.

In case of link rot, I'll paste my solution here, skipping over the bits where I run into all of the same problems that I'm sure you did.

---

First, let’s create a *universal* `post-receive` hook, one that I won’t need to change on a per-repository basis:

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ cat > /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-receive.sample
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to update the working tree, including its
# submodules, after receiving a push.
#
# This hook requires core.worktree to be explicitly set, and
# receive.denyCurrentBranch to be set to false.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-receive".

# Read standard input or hook will fail
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
:
done

# Unset GIT_DIR or the universe will implode
unset GIT_DIR

# Change directory to the working tree; exit on failure
cd `git config --get core.worktree` || exit

# Force checkout
git checkout --force

# Force update submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
[aaron@aaronadams]$ chmod +x /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-receive.sample
```

Now let’s go ahead and break all the rules.

We’re going to initialize a *non-bare* Git repository, right in our website directory; make sure it can receive from `git push`; explicitly set its working tree to its parent directory; and enable our hook we just created.

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ cd /var/www/vhosts/aaronadams.ca/sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git init && git config --bool receive.denyCurrentBranch false && git config --path core.worktree ../ && mv .git/hooks/post-receive.sample .git/hooks/post-receive
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/vhosts/aaronadams.ca/sites/staging.aaronadams.ca/.git/
```

Finally, on our local machine, we’ll change our remote to reflect the location of our new repository, and push.

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git remote set-url staging aaron@aaronadams.ca:sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git push staging master
remote: Submodule 'codeigniter' (git://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter.git) registered for path 'codeigniter'
remote: Cloning into 'codeigniter'...
remote: Submodule path 'codeigniter': checked out 'fd24adf31255822d6aa9a5d2dce9010ad2ee4cf0'
To aaron@aaronadams.ca:sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Holy crap, it worked!

Not only is this method compatible with submodules, it also requires just **one command to set up a new remote repository** (which, okay, consists of four commands). It also keeps the repository and the working tree in the same place; and with no absolute paths required in our configuration or hook files, it’s now **completely portable** as well.

---

I hope this answer helps somebody as much as everyone else's Stack Exchange posts helped me over the last two days!

Comment: I tried your article but after the first push it breaks. I notice it is not storing files in the objects directory. The error is: error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename ./objects/9e: No such file or directory. I believe it should be .git/objects/9e. Any ideas? This is very close

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like your configuration maybe ended up a little different from mine in the end – but hey, as long as it's working!

Comment: This will likely cause problems if multiple programmers are deploying to the same website. See ["all about bare repos"](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html). VonC's solution avoids this hiccup.

Comment: @jrhorn424 Indeed, there's lots wrong with the above solution; I've learned plenty since I wrote it, the most important being that submodules create more problems than they solve. I'd strongly recommend switching to the submodule-free solution I've documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656047/how-do-i-add-upgrade-downgrade-a-remote-git-project-in-my-repository-without-usi

Comment: Thanks, @AaronAdams. Good write up. Actually, I couldn't get VonC's solution to work after all, and this "fake bare" technique is actually used by [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh). Since my use case is dotfiles, I think this is OK, but I wouldn't use it for websites.

Comment: @jrhorn424 Indeed, my original blog post documents all of the pains I encountered in attempting to implement that solution myself.

Comment: @AaronAdams I think this is more of a overkill.

Comment: @AbuShumon Hey man, could be. The Internet didn't work that great in 2013. There are almost certainly better solutions in 2019.