# How to Upgrade and Deploy WordPress Install as a Git Submodule?

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment

I am using a WordPress directory struture similar to Mark Jaquith's [WordPress Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton), which has WordPress in a separate directory from the content as a submodule:

```
/content
/wp
/local-config.php
/wp-config.php
/index.php
```

I also use git and post-receive hooks to push my code changes up to my live server. It all works great except for when I try to upgrade WordPress and push that up to the live server.

This is how I setup the repo on my local machine and the remote server:

### Local Machine

```
cd /www
git init .
git submodule add git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git wp
git commit -m "Add Wordpress submodule."
cd wp
git checkout 3.5
```

After checking out the tag, I get a warning from git about being in a 'detached HEAD' state. Since I don't plan on making any commits to WordPress, I don't think that should be an issue.

```
cd ..
git commit -am "Checkout Wordpress 3.5"
```

### Remote Server

```
git init --bare
cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/public git checkout -f

chmod +x hooks/post-receive

git remote add web ssh://user@server/home/private/code/wordpress.git

git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

I get this error:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://userserver/home/private/code/wordpress.git'
```

After some googling, it looks like I can use this command to sync up the master branch up to the server (I have no idea how this works)

```
git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

This doesn't help me though because I don't want to track master, I want to track a release tag, 3.5. Some more googling got me to this command:

```
git push web +3.5~0:refs/heads/master
```

To upgrade the submodule, I do this:

```
cd wp
git fetch && git fetch --tags
git checkout 3.5.1
git push web +3.5.1~0:refs/heads/master
```

Am I doing this correctly? All the tutorials I see for this just have `git push web` and they're done. Most don't even cover upgrading the submodule. This does **work** but I don't feel comfortable using this weird push syntax if I don't have to.

How do I push this detached HEAD state up to the server correctly?

I've also tried this using a branch with `git checkout -b mywp 3.5` but when it comes time to upgrade, I don't know how to bring in the new 3.5.1 tag into my `mywp` branch.

*Asked this on [WP Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83063/how-to-upgrade-and-deploy-wordpress-install-as-a-git-submodule#comment112509_83063), but it might be more appropriate here.*

Comment: Is the solution here to checkout the tag onto a branch initially and then run some type of merge when a new tag is updated?

Answer (score 3):

On the remote server try:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This will update all your submodules recursively

You can also issue:

```
git fetch --tags
```

This will update your local tags fetching updated list from the central remote repo.

Comment: My remote is a bare repo, is it still possible to run these commands? Can I run submodule update without pushing anything to the submodule repo?

Comment: I think [this StackOverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448682/git-submodule-on-remote-bare) might be really helpfull.