# Git clone --mirror with submodules not working

Tags: git

Why is it that

`git clone --mirror [repo-url]`

or

`git clone --mirror --recursive [repo-url]`

will not work with submodules. Trying to `git fetch --recurse-submodules` gives the error

`fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository`

Excluding `--mirror` however does work.

So if the repository has been cloned with `--mirror` option, there is no way to bring the submodules in, unless the repository is cloned without `--mirror`.

Running `git submodule update --init --recursive` from the working copy gives the error message:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Running `git submodule init` from the mirrored repository gives this error message:

`fatal: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-submodule cannot be used without a working tree.`

Using `GIT_WORK_TREE` and/or `GIT_DIR` environment variables also does not work.

Is the only option to clone the repository from scratch again?

Edit: By the way, the reason for `--mirror` in the first place was because I was following this: http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository you create with `--mirror` flag is a bare repository (i.e. it does not have a working area). AFAIK, submodules can be initialized and downloaded only into working area.

More:

- [Git submodule on remote bare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448682/git-submodule-on-remote-bare)
- [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

Comment: After creating the repository I would run `cd ~/<repo-name>.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/<username>/www git checkout -f production` and still cannot get the submodules from the working area or repo directories. It seems strange that by cloning a repository in this way that submodules cannot be gotten at a later time. Surely it is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help, from your link, this solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31627058/644721