# git submodule update --recursive --remote

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621245/1979665):

> git submodule update --remote will only update the branch registered
>   in the .gitmodule (...)
>
> ...
>
> (...) you still have to go back to the parent repo, add and commit the new
>   submodule SHA1 reference.

And according to [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864099/1979665):

> > Or do I have to tell my colleagues to pay more attention and do a git
> >     submodule update from time to time?
>
> Ideally this is what they do. If they don't, you could try to add a
>   git-hook which runs a git submodule update after they pulled.

I am working on my own from two different machines. My repo has a submodule in it.

When I need to upodate it normally I do `git submodule update --recursive --remote`. And then, I do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "submodule updated"
git push origin master
```

The problem is, from the other machine, I pull the changes from the remote `git pull origin master`, then I update the submodule with the same code (`git submodule update --recursive --remote`), but then I seem I have to still add commit and push those changes again to the remote.

Is this the correct way to proceed?

If so, why should I have to push the updates to submodule twice to the remote?